# eclipse java annotation processing

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-indigo, apt, annotation-processing

I want to do something using Annotation processing in eclipse jdt.

Eclipse jdtapt help tells me I should configure things on the java/compiler/annotation processing preferences page.

But on my installation (Indigo), the compiler section doesn't have this annotation processing subsection.  It only has building,errors/warnings,javadoc, task tags.

Is something wrong with my installation ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The annotation processing tab does not exist in the Preferences page that is accessible from the Eclipse menu bar. It is a project-specific menu that is accessible if you right-click on a project in the Project Explorer and select Preferences in the pop-up menu that will appear.

You may have to enable project-specific settings for the Java compiler tab and annotation processing explicitly before it will appear, as mentioned in [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20150831073348/http://kerebus.com/2011/02/using-java-6-processors-in-eclipse).

Comment: I have these enabled, but I still do not get the option for Annotation Processing

Comment: The "Enable specific settings" seems to say that there are global settings for that, but it seems untrue.
Also, link is down...

Answer (score 5):

I autogenerate my eclipse project files, so I prefer setting this stuff w/o using the UI ...

project/.factorypath:

```
<factorypath>
    <factorypathentry kind="WKSPJAR" id="../build/EpicBuilder.jar" enabled="true" runInBatchMode="false"/>
</factorypath>
```

project/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.prefs:

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
org.eclipse.jdt.apt.aptEnabled=true
org.eclipse.jdt.apt.genSrcDir=.apt_generated
org.eclipse.jdt.apt.reconcileEnabled=true
```

project/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs:

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.processAnnotations=enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are running a **multi-module** project. You are looking for the  annotation processing tab in the parent project which might have a `<packaging>pom</packaging>` in its `pom.xml`

If so, you won't find the tab here. Go to a specific project with packaging `jar` and you will see the tab.

I search for this a few hours, so maybe this helps someone saving time.

Answer (score 0):

I spent full day , you can do it next way:

0. add lombok to maven pom.xml
1. install eclipse
2. download lombok
3. copy to eclipse folder
4. add to file eclipse.ini next text `-javaagent:lombok.jar`
5. active annotation processing in:

   - select project(not the parent) ->properties->Java compiler ->annotation processing
   - Select Enable project specific settings
   - Select all Enable checkbox
6. restart and it should work .

test ubuntu 20.04 and eclipse 2021 year