# Missing "Annotation processing" menu in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, annotations

I use this manual https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Eclipse-Only-Configuration

```
"5 Go to Java Compiler > Annotation Processing and choose Enable annotation processing"
```

But i have not Annotation Processing in Java Compiler (only Building, Error/Warnings, Javadoc, Task Tags). How to fix it?

```
ADT: 23.0.2
Eclipse: 4.2.1    
Java: 1.6
```

Comment: It seems your question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850952/eclipse-java-annotation-processing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to have been an Oopsy in the Android Development Toolkit build 23.0.2, and [should be fixed in 23.0.3](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73798). I haven't been able to find a way to just install APT on it's own, but if I find something, I'll definitely post it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I just install old eclipse (android bundle).

Answer (score 7):

I was able to work around this problem by installing Eclipse JDT.
Go to Help >> Install New Software... and select the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers version: 2019-03 (4.11.0).
I fixed it by follow steps.

- Go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace
- Find m2e-apt
- Install and restart Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

i have configured Android Annotations in Eclipse.
here is my Answer : [[AndroidAnnotations Eclipse configuration with ADT 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570629/androidannotations-eclipse-configuration-with-adt-23/25658422#25658422])